# ejecutar formularios en c# de forma dinámica

Tags: c#

Tengo una aplicacion que debe recordar cual fue la ultima ventana abierta y cuando la abran debe volver alli. asi que yo registro en un diario todo lo que pa persona hace, cuando vuelva a los dias siguientes la persona puede abrir el programa y este debe saber en que form estaba yo quiero que sea dinámico que saque el nombre del form de la base de datos y en una clase lo ejecute pero veo que no es posible

```
datos = "1,RegistroOrientador,true,Terminado";

 String[] campos = datos.Split(',');

 for (int i = 0; i < campos.Length; i++)
 {
     if (i == 1)
     {
         if (campos.Length >= 2)
         {
             campos[1] abrir = new campos[i]();
             abrir.visible =true;


         }


     }
    
 }
```

Comment: eh.. que??? no entendi absolutamente nada de tu problema.. que es ejecutar en forma dinamica?? que queres hacer con tus form???

Comment: Mira tengo un fomulario llamado RegistroOrientador.cs y que quiero que cuando se recorra ese array donde esta "RegistroOrientador.cs" de imediato se ejecute en el bucle. SI miras en el blucle tengo campos[1] abrir = new campos[i]();
             abrir.visible =true; se supone que al ejecutarse campo[1]  llevaria el nombre del formulario RegistroOrientador.cs, uno esperaria que se ejecutará pero no pasa eso.

Comment: no, nunca esperaria que eso se ejecutara, porque campos es un array de string, no es un form.. por mas que tenga el nombre del form, no es un form. Y porque querrias hacer algo asi??? no le veo sentido, pero si le decis que es del tipo RegistroOrientador seguro se va a ejecutar...

Comment: Porque tengo una aplicacion que debe recordar cual fue la ultima ventana abierta y cuando la abran debe volver alli. asi que yo registro en un diario todo lo que pa persona hace, cuando vuelva a los dias siguientes la persona puede abrir el programa y este debe saber en que form estaba yo quiero que sea dinámico que saque el nombre del form de la base de datos y en una clase lo ejecute pero veo que no es posible.

Comment: Si que es posible, pero ahora tu explicacion es muy diferente a lo que pusiste arriba ;) asi que por favor, en la pregunta, explica esto, pone el codigo, y se puede hacer de varias maneras...  el form es una clase que tranquilamente puede heredar o implementar una interfaz con la cual podes interactuar.. tambien podes llegar a la coleccion forms por reflection.. habria (teoricamente) varias formas de hacerlo...

Comment: wpf o winforms??? de cualquier forma, creo que los metodos funcionan para todos igual, pero por si acaso no esta de mas aclararlo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguro hay más formas de hacerlo, pero la version simple seria guardar en la db un dato (por ejemplo un numero) que identifique al form, y luego de eso, hacer un gran switch en el punto de entrada, que decida que form tiene que abrir.

Por ejemplo:

```
switch (miFormulario)
    case 1:
        form1 miformulario = new form1();
        miformulario.showmodal(); //o lo que sea que uses para prenderlo
        break;
    case 2:
        form2 miformulario = new form2();
        miformulario.showmodal(); //o lo que sea que uses para prenderlo
        break;
    etc....
```

Aunque este metodo es trivial, seguro funciona al menos para empezar.